# PHP - retrieve first element of json string without converting to array

Tags: php, json

I have a json string, which I am currently probing as follows:

```
$playedOn = $query -> data -> artist -> services_played_on
```

I now want to get the first element of this services_played_on, but am unsure how to do this..  If it were an array I'd just do $query[data][artist][services_played_on][0], but for various reasons this would mess up other code that I have.  Anyone have any ideas how I can do this using the `->` notation?

-----EDIT-----

Thanks for your answers, but what I needed was:

```
$playedOn = $query -> data -> artist -> services_played_on[0]
```

(I can't submit this as an answer yet, as I am a 'new' user)

Comment: Whats the matter with just `$tmp = json_decode($query, true); $tmp['data']['artist']['services_played_on'][0]; unset($tmp);`?!

Comment: What does the JSON look like, are you sure `services_played_on` isn't an array already?

Comment: I have to agree with the others. Why don't you want to decode the json array? It doesn't make much sense, and will involve a much more complex operation.

Answer (score 13):

Just [decode the JSON](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first.

```
$jset = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jset["data"]["artist"]["services_played_on"][0];
```

Comment: @tiswas: See my comment above. There is no good reason to _not_ decode it first. If not, you must interact with the string representation, which makes everything incomparably more complex.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see your problem. If it is JSON, simply deserialize it to PHP as @Marcel said.

If you want the result to be JSON, simply serialize it back.

Example:

```
$json = '[ {"a":1} , {"d":3} , {"b":2} ]';

$data = json_decode( $json );

$new = json_encode( $data[1] ); // $new is now '{"d":3}'
```

Since your question is quite ambiguous, I'm not sure if you want the result to be JSON encoded OR whether you want to split the string your own way.